# Draw points in OpenGL with QVector3D

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qtgui, qvector3d

I have a list of `QVector3D`, which is a list of points, I want to draw a list of points with `glDrawArrays`.

```
initializeGLFunctions();

glGenBuffers(2, vbo);
//the vertices 
QVector3D *vertices = &data[0];

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(QVector3D), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,??);
```

or what other method I can use to deal with this?

Comment: If the data is correctly stored in the vbo, you can just use `glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, data.size());`, as written [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml).

Comment: @SebastianHöffner,how can OpenGL recognize QVector3D?

Comment: @LaszloPapp，yes, as sebastian answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(QVector3D), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

This is correct, but I would suggest to use more intelligent containers like QVector outside an then constData as follows:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(QVector3D), myVector.constData(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Here is another official example how to use `glBufferData` in the context of `QVector3D`:

[geometryengine.cpp Example File](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-geometryengine-cpp.html)

Here can you find another third-party example following the official example:

[FabScan100](https://github.com/francisengelmann/FabScan100/blob/master/qtTest/geometryengine.cpp#L37)

Then, you could write:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, data.size());
```